# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import' when creating a dynamic icon

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to create a React component that uses an icon from our library. This icon name is received by a prop called `iconName` and is rendered dynamically based on if the `iconName` is present in our library or not.

```
  import * as LibIcons from '../components/icons';

  const Component = ({iconName}) => {
    const DynamicIcon = LibIcons[iconName];

    return <DynamicIcon />
  }
```

And this is my index.ts from the `../components/icons`:

```
export { Bottom } from './Bottom';
export { SelectedBottomBar } from './SelectedBottomBar';
export { UserPin } from './UserPin';
```

And the components works as expected but I started receiving a Typescript error on the DynamicIcon const line when trying to run the tests.

This is the error I get:

> error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("/home/src/components/Icons/index")'.

And I have no idea how to fix it.

This is what I have tried:

Typing `DynamicIcon`:

```
const DynamicIcon = LibIcons[iconName as string] as keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
```

The error still happening. I can't use `any` or `@ts-ignore` to follow the project rules. Can anyone please help me?

Typescript version: `4.2.4`

PS: I have searched for similar errors but none of them are using import like I am

Comment: You need to define a type for the `DynamicIcon` const when assigning it a component.

Comment: @HassanKhalid Thanks for the help. I have tried assigning it as a keyof JSX.IntrinsicElement but it wont work

Comment: nop @AakashGoplani. I ended up using the import in a different and simpler way